# Network Drive mount errors

Tags: mount, cifs

While I am trying to mount NFS GoFlexHome onto Ubuntu using cifs-utils, the below error props up.

`sb@sb-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo mount -t cifs "//192.168.1.14/bezgoan" -o user=bezgoan,vers=1.0 /mnt
Password for bezgoan@//192.168.1.14/bezgoan:  ************
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

I am able to directly load the NFS via the File Browser utility of Ubuntu, but the command line errors out.

Tried using smbclient as well. SmbClient doens't return the smb> prompt, but shows list of shares available

`sb@sb-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo smbclient -L //192.168.1.14/bezgoan -U bezgoan
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter WORKGROUP\bezgoan's password:`

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
GoFlex Home Personal Disk      GoFlex Home (GoFlex Home Personal)
GoFlex Home Backup Disk      GoFlex Home (GoFlex Home Backup)
GoFlex Home Public Disk      GoFlex Home (GoFlex Home Public)
External Storage Disk      GoFlex Home (External Storage)
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (GoFlex Home)
GoFlex_Home     Printer   GoFlex Home usb port
```

Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

```
Server               Comment
---------            -------

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
HOME                 BTHUB5
SEAGATEGROUP         GOFLEX_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to connect by specifying the smbClient version to be 1.0 in this case.